# What is the difference between slugurl and pageurl in wagtil

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet, wagtail-slugurl, wagtail-pageurl

I have two major query related to slugurl  and pageurl:

What is the exact difference between  `slugurl`  and `pageurl`?

Why `slugurl`  returning **None** ?

Answer (score 2):

After debugging the source code found this in side the [slugurl](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c82b6835a009d57417551efe4da4ed677f724699/wagtail/core/templatetags/wagtailcore_tags.py#L36)  simple tag.

```
    @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
    def slugurl(context, slug):
        """Returns the URL for the page that has the given slug."""
        page = Page.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()

        if page:
            # call pageurl() instead of page.relative_url() here so we get the ``accepts_kwarg`` logic
            return pageurl(context, page)
```

1: What is the exact difference between  `slugurl` and `pageurl`?

Both `slugurl` and `pageurl`  are the [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

`slugurl` take **slug string** as the input where as `pageurl` take **page object** at the input.

NOTE: `slugurl` internally call the `pageurl`, if the page found with the mention string slug.

2: Why slugurl returning **None**.?

If you passing any string( let say 'hello') in the slugurl, then the string must be the slug of any `Page`

```
 page = Page.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
```

**If the mention string is not assign as the slug of any page, the method will return None**

In case you are facing the None issue with `slugurl` then follow these two simple steps:

1:Firstly check that any of your page have the mention slug or not.

2:In case of not, please create a page and assign the same slug string in the slug of the newly create page.